# How to plot time intervals without date components on the x-axis using dygraph and xts function?

Tags: r, datetime, posixct, chron, r-dygraphs

I'm trying to plot time series with the `dygraph` function. A single diagram represents the course of a specific variable on different days. Since series correspond to different days, I would like the x-axis to be date-agnostic. It should only contain time-intervals.

When I generate a time sequence with:

`ts <- seq(as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 00:00:00"),as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 23:30:00"), by = "30 min")`

and make a plot using it:

```
d <- data.frame(
    time = ts,
    profile1 = ...,
    profile2 = ...,
    profile3 = ...
  )
  
  don=xts(x=d[,c("profile1", "profile2", "profile3")], order.by=d$time)
```

I obtain a date used for creating the time sequence on the axis, which is not desirable:

[image]

I combed through the SO, looking for a method to obtain only time intervals from dates but presented methods do not help - results are rejected by the `order.by` component of the `xts(...)` function.

I have tried the following (`ts` is the sequence defined above):

1. `strftime(ts, format = "%H:%M:%S")` -> Error: `order.by requires an appropriate time-based object`
2. chron

```
ts <- chron(times. = ts)
Error in convert.times(times., fmt) : format h:m:s may be incorrect
Additionaly: Warning:
In convert.times(times., fmt) : NAs obtained
```

3. 1 & 2 combined:

```
  ts <- strftime(ts, format = "%H:%M:%S")
  ts <- chron(times. = ts)
Fehler in as.POSIXct.default(order.by) : 
  do not know how to convert 'order.by' to class “POSIXct”
```

Moreover, I would like the x-axis to be formatted in such a way that it shows the timespan between 00:00 to 00:00 if possible. Right now, as you can see in the picture, it starts with a date and ends without any interval info, there is just an empty space there.

Comment: Why not use `numeric` as your timeline rather than POSIX?

Comment: Because order.by won't accept it as it expects a timebased format ("Date", "POSIXt", "chron", "dates", "times", "timeDate", "yearmon", "yearqtr", "xtime").